# Cannot return a jsx inside a map function

Tags: reactjs, return

I cannot display my message and i think that's because of my ChatRoom component codes has some problem in the map and return statement, can anyone help me to fix this error? Thank you so much!

Here the error:
./src/App.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Admin\superchat\src\App.js: Unexpected token (90:16)

```
88 |     return ( < div > {
  89 |             messages && messages.map(msg =>
> 90 |                 return <
     |                 ^
  91 |                     ChatMessage key = {
  92 |                         msg.id
  93 |                     }
```

My js:

```
function ChatRoom() {
    const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
    const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

    const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, {
        idField: 'id'
    });

    return ( <div> 
      { messages && messages.map(msg =>
                return <
                    ChatMessage key = {
                        msg.id
                    }
                message = {
                    msg
                }
                />
               )} 
        < /div>
        )
    }

    function ChatMessage() {
        const {
            uid,
            text
        } = props.message

        return 
        <p> {text} </p>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `return` part to :

```
return ( <div> 
  {messages && messages.map(msg => return <ChatMessage key = {msg.id} message = {msg}/>)} 
    </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work, i believe u are missing a parenthesis.

```
return ( <div> 
      { messages && messages.map(msg =>
                return (<
                    ChatMessage key = {
                        msg.id
                    }
                message = {
                    msg
                }
                />)
               )} 
        < /div>
        )
    }
```

and since u are wrapping everything in a div u better be using a span element or React.Fragment.